# SQLlite left-join referencing only bringing back results for one of the tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a bit of a problem performing a left-join. Its not bringing back the data I am expecting. It is only bringing back data from one part of the table. I am still learning some concepts and am a beginner with SQL so forgive my lack of knowledge, I am making mistakes and learning as I go along.

Here is my table data:

Departments:
[image]

Locations:
[image]

Here is my query:

```
$query = 'SELECT d.id as departmentId, d.name as departmentName, d.locationID as departmentLocation FROM department d LEFT JOIN location l ON (d.locationID = l.id)';

$result = $conn->query($query);
```

I am receiving the data from an AJAX get method and when it arrives, it only gives me the data from the departments table, but I am also trying to get the location name from the locations table.

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong here (I realize it may be something embarrassingly simple!) I've tried one or two different things but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the location name in the query:

```
$query = 'SELECT d.id as departmentId, d.name as departmentName, l.name as departmentLocation FROM department d LEFT JOIN location l ON (d.locationID = l.id)';
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @tino.codes but how exactly would I place it in the above query, does it come after the brackets of linking the id's?

Comment: I have already added the location with "l.name as departmentLocation" in my query